# Typescript tuple rxj6 switchMap

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, tuples, angular6

I have 2 function as follows

```
findCourseByUrl(courseUrl:string):Observable<Course>


findLessonsForCourse(courseId:string) : Observable<Lesson[]>
```

Following is the implementation of a type script class

```
export class CourseDetailResover implements Resolve<[Course,Lesson[]]>  {

    constructor(private coursesService:CoursesService){}

    resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, 
        state: RouterStateSnapshot):Observable<[Course,(Lesson[])]> {
        return this.coursesService.findCourseByUrl(route.params['id'])
            .pipe(
            switchMap(
             course => this.coursesService.findLessonsForCourse(course.id)
             .pipe(map((course,lessons) => [course,lessons]))
            )
            );
    }
}
```

I get the following compilation error

```
ERROR in src/app/course-detail/course-detail-resolver.ts(18,9): error TS2322: Type 'Observable<(number | Lesson[])[]>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<[Course, Lesson[]]>'.
  Type '(number | Lesson[])[]' is not assignable to type '[Course, Lesson[]]'.
    Property '0' is missing in type '(number | Lesson[])[]'.
```

How can I resolve this error and make the `resolve` function return a tuple

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a slight error in the map function that causes `lessons` to be a number. The `map` operator takes a callback that accepts the stream value as the first argument and an index value as a second. You want the first argument to be the lessons object as a result of the `findLessonsForCourse` method. You also need to explicitly set the return type of the map otherwise it will assume an array of union-ed types. E.G.

```js
resolve(
  route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, 
  state: RouterStateSnapshot,
): Observable<[Course,Lesson[]]> {
    return this.coursesService.findCourseByUrl(route.params['id'])
      .pipe(
        switchMap(
          course => this.coursesService.findLessonsForCourse(course.id).pipe(
            map<Lesson[], [Course, Lesson[]]>(lessons => [course,lessons])
          )
       )
     );
}
```